# remove global variables in c++ program

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have a large program in c++ having too many function and global variables. Now, I want to remove those global variables and I want to use only local variables rather than global variables. Can any one suggest me the best way to do this.
Thanks!

Its around 4000 lines program in C++. There are 10 classes and 60 functions in those different classes, 30 global variables. The global variables have used between functions of different classes.

Comment: How large is it? Can you throw it away and rewrite it?

Comment: I think you can post your code to Code Review StackExchange site to ask for suggestion.

Answer (score 22):

I normally start by putting the global variables in a namespace

```
namespace global
{
  int var;
  ...
}
```

this will cause you to get errors everwhere that 'var' is used, then i would just replace the references one by one to the namespace variant. once all global variable references are in the namespace it is easier to see which variables are local and which are global

```
if ( global::var == 1 ) ...
```

now by searching `global::var` you get a list of variables where it is used then you would need to go through the usage case by case to see if a variable is used in several modules or not, in those cases you may need to pass it in as a function argument in other cases declare it is a local variable.

its a cumbersome method but eliminating global vars is always worth doing.

Comment: I downvoted when I saw the first half, but removed it when I read the second.  Interesting thought process.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a solution such as removing their declarations from global scope and put them in the appreciated functions.

Examlpe:

```
int hello; // global
// remove it
```

Now, put it in the function:

```
void func()
{
   int hello; // local
  //...
```

We have two cases:

> If some other function needs to know the value of `hello`, let it take that `hello` as a parameter:

```
void func2(const int &helloVar)
{
   // ...
```

> If a global variable is used only by a single function, you can use a `static` local variable instead..

Comment: Be careful with statics! You may get different copies per thread depending on your compiler settings. Also, even if they use the same storage, you have concurrency issues to watch out for.

Comment: this doesn't cover the case where func2 isn't called from within func(). in this case both functions need `hello` as a parameter. also you are assuming that func2 doesn't need to change it's parameter which isn't always intended...

Comment: In this situation, `hello` would be declared in `main()` and passed to both functions. Since `func2` always needs `hello` for its operation, it doesn't really need to change its parameter at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a class. They are perfect for hiding variables and functions into one group and categorizing. Here is the basic structure:

```
class example
{
public:
    example(); //basic constructor
    int function1();  //example function
    int x;  // a variable accesible globally
private:
    int y;  // a variable only accesible by functions of the class
};
```

Calling each function is easy but I wont explain since I dont want to start a text wall. You can go to this link for more information: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Comment: Why use a class when a namespace would do the job? C++ is not Java, not everything has to be inside a class.

Comment: global variables have used between function of different classes, So how can I use class there?

Answer (score 0):

you can put those variables in aclass , then create pointer to object of that class in the 1st place will use those variables then pass this pointer to every methode need those variables , don`t forget to delete the object when you will not use .