# The best way to avoid using lots of global variables or make them easy to access and modify

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm translating an old project, written before object oriented programming became something that is common and I have lots of global variables there. It's a project written in Pascal and I try to rewrite it in modern c++11 way, as well as trying to achieve the most possible portability as I can.

And my purpose is to make the project easy to modify for other people. And my problem is that I get lots of LNK2019 errors in Visual Studio right now due to these variables are not well declared.

The thing is that I have some header files that are full of global variables like

```
bool DS_Flag_0;
...
bool DS_Flag_11;
```

and

```
typedef unsigned short int UInt16;
//...

const UInt16 DayManth;
const UInt16 DayYear;
const UInt16 DayLongYear;
const UInt16 DayPer;

const int SecMin;
const double SecQuart; 
const double SecClock;
const double SecHalfDay; 
const double SecDay;
const double SecWeek;
const double SecYear;
const double SecPer;
```

And I need somehow to use all of these variables inside of my project in almost every file possible. (Yes, that's a really bad designed project but I do not have that much time to rebuild it from scratch so..)

There are some options that I see:

1. Use "extern" modifier and create lots of ".cpp" initialization files because I need to initialize those as well
2. Somehow make it possible (may be) to initialize all of them inside of ".h" headers. It this a good programming practice if I want to make the project readable for other people?
3. Maybe I somehow can implement object-oriented patterns here to avoid lots of variables and make it more modern, can I?

The purpose of the project is to translate lots of satellite messages from binary file data into another binary format and I need at first to get it to work with these data (but this information is not that neccessary to answer the question).

Update: 
To be more certain, I have many variables inside of files with namespace "Prm" and "Prm_BinDS".

I have Files "Prm_IDD_VAR.h", "Prm_BinDS_MayUnit_Data.h" and "Prm_IDD_VAR.h" and they all share the "Prm" namespace. There are vars of type "bool", structs with types of "UInt16, float, double and unsigned char", single unsigned chars, floats, doubles and even std::string's and arrays of all of these types.

```
namespace Prm {
bool GPS_FlagL1[33];
...
bool Gali_FlagL3[51];
//...
}
```

All of these vars have to be initialized inside of the extern ".cpp"s and I also want to make them have initial values. Is this also possible to initialize them somehow to all zeros when they are declared? (I heard that if I use 'static' - I can't use my global variables anywhere except for the file where they are declared)

Comment: To initialise them inside the header files, it's probably sufficient to declare them as `static const X x = value;`

Comment: @SirGuy: Note the `double` there. It works for contant _integral_ expressions.

Comment: What's wrong with declaring them in a header (with an `extern`), including that header wherever you need the globals, and defining them in a single source file?

Comment: c.f. [remove global variables in c++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606532/remove-global-variables-in-c-program)

Comment: OT: Title of the question seems to contradict the content. Title suggest you want to move away from using global variables, but the content suggests that you can't rewrite the code, so that it wouldn't use the globals (which would be the proper response to the question in the title - rewrite the code, so it wouldn't use the globals).

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius, yes, you're right. I accidentally didn't take enough time to consider the right title. Now I made it more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh dear... Having had the joy of wrestling with a 1000LoC functions (which liberally accessed various global variables) I can sympathize.

First of all, I'd strongly reccommend you to get and read the book "Working Effectively with Legacy Code" by Michael C. Feathers. It will give a lot of good ideas how to work, well, with the code you have.

Secondly: Consider your testing procedures. I assume that the new program is expected to work like the old pascal one, so make sure you have a solid set of tests to verify that.

Finally: There are several ways to get such a global variable blob under control. The best option (in the medium and long term) would probably be to untangle that ball of yarn, pack global variables that belong together into structs or classes, and use dependency injection to get them to the objects (and functions) that need them (i.e. the constructor of such classes demands a pointer to said struct).

```
//FlagsStruct.h
struct FlagsStruct
{
    int Flag_1;
    int Flag_2;
}

//WorksWithFlags.h    
class WorksWithFlags
{
  public:
    WorksWithFlags(FlagsStruct* flags);
    //...
}
```

That way you need to create the FlagsStruct once (and only once), then hand it to all those that need to work with it.

And regarding the const values - that is pretty much the only way to handle consts. You could too partition those up into groups that belong together and create individiual header files (with them as static consts in them) for those, but beyond that I don't see much that you could do about them. On the postive side: consts are (being read-only) rather benign "globals".

Answer (score 6):

Roughly you need to do this:

**variables.h**

```
// declare all global variables

extern int global1;
extern int global2;
extern int global3;
...
```

**variables.cpp**

```
// define all global variables

int global1;
int global2 = 123;   // initializing variable to something else than 0
int global3;
```

**somefile.cpp**

```
#include "variables.h"    
...
printd("Global1 = %d\n", global1);
...
```

**someotherfile.cpp**

```
#include "variables.h"    
...
global1 = foo;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The best practice would probably be separating declaration and definition manually. If you know how to use a few command line utilities, like `sed`, things will be very easy:

```
typedef unsigned short int UInt16;
//...

extern const UInt16 DayManth;
extern const UInt16 DayYear;
extern const UInt16 DayLongYear;
extern const UInt16 DayPer;

extern const int SecMin;
extern const double SecQuart; 
extern const double SecClock;
extern const double SecHalfDay; 
extern const double SecDay;
extern const double SecWeek;
extern const double SecYear;
extern const double SecPer;
```

The above could be done by one line of command:

```sh
sed -E 's/^((?:const )?(?:double|UInt16|int))/extern \1/1' whatever.cpp > globals.h
```

And rename the original file to `globals.cpp`

Answer (score 0):

First, about your typedef: There's a standard type - both in C and C++ - for an unsigned 16-bit integer: `std::uint16_t` in `<cstdint>` (which is `<stdint.h>` in C). You should probably be using that.

Now, your global constants seem to be made up of two groups: `Day` and `Sec`. My guess would be that they would probably fit in existing classes, but given only what you've shown us, I wound consider having the following:

**in file `global_constants.h`**:

```
struct Day {
    static const uint16_t Month; // fixed your typo
    static const uint16_t Year;
    static const uint16_t LongYear;
    static const uint16_t Per; // confusing name here...
};

struct Sec { // is that "Second" perhaps?
    static const int Min; // minutes, perhaps?
    static const double Quart;   
    static const double Clock;
    static const double HalfDay; 
    static const double Day;
    static const double Week;
    static const double Year;
    static const double Per; // again, a confusing name
}
```

and define these values in a separate file, e.g.

**in file `global_constants.cpp`**:

```
// ...
const double Sec::Year = 1.0;
// ...
```

but again, judging from the names I'm guessing there's a fair chance you don't really need most/any of them at all.

Comment: Those name have been given by a completely non-english-speaking person. So I could have posted them all .. And I probably should have but it's beyond the scope of the question, i think. And these names are not only ones that are confusing :D the  code is full of them, I first want to get the code to work ;)